# Threads interaction (data from one thread to another) c#

Tags: c#, .net, winforms

I need to pass information from thread of scanning data to recording information thread(write to xml file).
It should looks something like this:

Application.Run() - complete

Scanning thread - complete

Writing to xlm thread - ???

UI update thread - I think I did it

And what i got now:

```
        private void StartButtonClick(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (FolderPathTextBox.Text == String.Empty || !Directory.Exists(FolderPathTextBox.Text)) return;
        {
            var nodeDrive = new TreeNode(FolderPathTextBox.Text);
            FolderCatalogTreeView.Nodes.Add(nodeDrive);
            nodeDrive.Expand();
            var t1 = new Thread(() => AddDirectories(nodeDrive));
            t1.Start();
        }
    }

     private void AddDirectories(TreeNode node)
    {
        string strPath = node.FullPath;
        var dirInfo = new DirectoryInfo(strPath);
        DirectoryInfo[] arrayDirInfo;
        FileInfo[] arrayFileInfo;

        try
        {
            arrayDirInfo = dirInfo.GetDirectories();
            arrayFileInfo = dirInfo.GetFiles();
        }
        catch
        {

            return;
        }

      //Write data to xml file
        foreach (FileInfo fileInfo in arrayFileInfo)
        {
            WriteXmlFolders(null, fileInfo);
        }
        foreach (DirectoryInfo directoryInfo in arrayDirInfo)
        {
            WriteXmlFolders(directoryInfo, null);
        }


        foreach (TreeNode nodeFil in arrayFileInfo.Select(file => new TreeNode(file.Name)))
        {
            FolderCatalogTreeView.Invoke(new ThreadStart(delegate { node.Nodes.Add(nodeFil); }));
        }

        foreach (TreeNode nodeDir in arrayDirInfo.Select(dir => new TreeNode(dir.Name)))
        {
            FolderCatalogTreeView.Invoke(new ThreadStart(delegate
                {node.Nodes.Add(nodeDir);
                }));

            StatusLabel.BeginInvoke(new MethodInvoker(delegate
                {
     //UI update...some code here
                }));
            AddDirectories(nodeDir);
        }
    }

      private void WriteXmlFolders(DirectoryInfo dir, FileInfo file)
    {//writing information into the file...some code here}
```

How to pass data from AddDirectories(recursive method) thread to WriteXmlFolders thread?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/334860/in-c-sharp-what-is-the-recommended-way-of-passing-data-between-2-threads

Comment: Take a look at a producer consumer.  http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd267312.aspx  http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd267312.aspx

Comment: Thx for answers, me hope that BackgroundWorker what I need. Update: BlockingCollection looks more attractive and have to make a lot less changes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a generic mechanism how one thread generates data that another thread consumes. No matter what approach (read: ready made classes) you would use the internal principle stays the same. The main players are (note that there are many locking classes available in `System.Threading` namespace that could be used but these are the most appropriate for this scenario:

`AutoResetEvent` - this allows a thread to go into sleep mode (without consuming resources) until another thread will wake it up. The 'auto' part means that once the thread wakes up, the class is reset so the next `Wait()` call will again put it in sleep, without the need to reset anything.

`ReaderWriterLock` or `ReaderWriterLockSlim` (recommended to use the second if you are using .NET 4) - this allows just one thread to lock for writing data but multiple threads can read the data. In this particular case there is only one reading thread but the approach would not be different if there were many.

```
// The mechanism for waking up the second thread once data is available
AutoResetEvent _dataAvailable = new AutoResetEvent();

// The mechanism for making sure that the data object is not overwritten while it is being read.
ReaderWriterLockSlim _readWriteLock = new ReaderWriterLockSlim();

// The object that contains the data (note that you might use a collection or something similar but anything works
object _data = null;

void FirstThread()
{
    while (true)
    {
        // do something to calculate the data, but do not store it in _data

        // create a lock so that the _data field can be safely updated.
        _readWriteLock.EnterWriteLock();
        try
        {
            // assign the data (add into the collection etc.)
            _data = ...;

            // notify the other thread that data is available
            _dataAvailable.Set();
        }
        finally
        {
            // release the lock on data
            _readWriteLock.ExitWriteLock();
        }
    }
}

void SecondThread()
{
    while (true)
    {
        object local; // this will hold the data received from the other thread

        // wait for the other thread to provide data
        _dataAvailable.Wait();

        // create a lock so that the _data field can be safely read
        _readWriteLock.EnterReadLock();
        try
        {
            // read the data (add into the collection etc.)
            local = _data.Read();
        }
        finally
        {
            // release the lock on data
            _readWriteLock.ExitReadLock();
        }

        // now do something with the data
    }
}
```

In .NET 4 it is possible to avoid using `ReadWriteLock` and use one of the concurrency-safe collections such as [`ConcurrentQueue`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd267265.aspx) which will internally make sure that reading/writing is thread safe. The `AutoResetEvent` is still needed though.

.NET 4 provides a mechanism that could be used to avoid the need of even `AutoResetEvent` - [`BlockingCollection`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd267312.aspx) - this class provides methods for a thread to sleep until data is available. [MSDN page](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd267312.aspx) contains example code on how to use it.

Answer (score 1):

In case you use it as the answer

Take a look at a producer consumer.

[BlockingCollection Class](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd267312.aspx)

[How to: Implement Various Producer-Consumer Patterns](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd728068.aspx)