# Orchestrator Thread Architecture design

Tags: c#, multithreading, sockets, design-patterns, architecture

I'm looking for advice to architect my piece of code. I need to write a program that will do 3 things:
1-open a socket to listen to a server (this socket can close, reopen...)
2-talk to a REST web Service
3-decides upon web service answer to send through the socket some request to the server.

What is the best .net architecture i should use?
A main thread, that manages a dedicated thread for socket communication, a third one for Rest web services?
Thanks
John

Comment: What's wrong with simple sequential execution on the main thread? First open a socket, then send, then receive. Like that.

Answer (score 1):

I think you already figured out the best way to do it, you should create 2 threads, one for the socket connection and one for the REST web-service.

The only problem is point 3, this will involve communication between 2 threads, which can be a pain whenever you fail to do this properly. Although, there are enough resources online to help you getting started:

[Advanced Threading - Nonblocking Synchronization, by Joseph Albahari](http://www.albahari.com/threading/part4.aspx) (find the paragraph: *Producer/Consumer Queue*)

[StackOverflow - Similar answer to as this question, also Queue's](https://stackoverflow.com/a/336438/2058541)